# Conditional Probability of not events

Tags: probability

If the probability of A is 0.25, the probability of S is 0.15 and the probability of A AND S is 0.1, what is the probability of;

(a) NOT S given A

(b) NOT A given NOT S

Comment: you can try to solve this by using venn diagram

Comment: Do you know how conditional probabilities are computed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's also nice to get a visual feel too. Below is a Venn diagram representation of your problem.

[image]

In **a)** you require $\text{Pr}(\bar{S}|A)$.Lets think of our probabilities as areas for a moment. Notice that this is then the same as asking,

> "What proportion of $\bar{S}$ sits inside of $A$".

What is the area of $A$? Well it's going to be the blue bit plus the purple bit, which is $0.25$.

Now, what is the area of $\bar{S}$ in $A$? Well, it's just the blue bit, which is $0.15$.

Therefore, the proportion of $\bar{S}$ that sits inside of $A$ is just $\frac{0.15}{0.25} = 0.60$.

You can carry the same ideas through to the next part of the question too.

Answer (score 1):

$$P(S'|A)=1-P(S|A)=1-\dfrac{P(A\cap S)}{P(A)}=0.6$$$$P(A'|S')=\dfrac{P(A'\cap S')}{P(S')}=\dfrac{1-P(A\cup S)}{1-P(S)}=\dfrac{0.7}{0.85}=\dfrac{7}{85}$$

Comment: So in your answer, P(A AND S) is equal to 0.06? Why is that, when the intersection is 0.1?